# Ionic 2 login flow with nav menu

Tags: authentication, ionic2

Ionic 2 allows a menu controller to show the standard hamburger nav menu toggle button in the nav bar. But by design, it only does this for the root page in the nav stack. The problem is that for an authenticated app, the login page needs to be the root page initially.

I can obviously set the root to the real root page after a successful login, but this causes two issues: 1) The nice page slide animation doesn't fire because it's not pushing a page onto the nav stack. 2) The menu hamburger isn't shown in that page even though it is the root.

This seems like a standard issue for most connected ionic apps, yet I can't find any complete examples. What's the recommended way to make this flow work (ideally without hacking past the built in menu management mechanism)?

**UPDATE:** The hamburger not showing (#2) was due to programmer error :( That's been resolved. Still looking for a solution to the animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.nav.setRoot(Page, {}, {animate: true, direction: 'forward'});`

Solution found [enter link description here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/is-it-possible-to-animate-this-nav-setroot/48196/2)

After googling 'animate ionic setroot'

Comment: Of course it would be that simple after all my searching :) Perfect. Thanks!